# Deinit in CoreData, Generic type

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I have some movie, book and series entities in my CoreData. I have also Images for each object in entity stored in Document Directory. When I delete my object, I have to delete an Image (I store only url in CoreData to my image)

I've wanted to make my List Of Objects View universal so I made it as Generic. I have a problem now. I have function calling on method `.onDelete` on each element of List. In this method I'm deleting image which is calling with imageName parameter. And there is a problem. I have an error which is saying that `T` object don't have `.id` attribute.

In C++ there is a rule that each class should clean for each self. So I thought that I could solve it with using deconstructs. In `deinit' I would write that if object has an image, it should delete it.

Where is a problem? I don't have an idea if it is possible to make such `deinit` because I don't have a class of my entities. CoreData made them.

Here is my Generic code, maybe there is another solution

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct FilteredList<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<T>
var objects: FetchedResults<T> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }
var wasSeen: Bool
let content: (T) -> Content

init(filter: Bool, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "seen == %@", NSNumber(value: filter))
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: predicate)
    self.wasSeen = filter
    self.content = content
}

var body: some View {
    List() {
        ForEach(objects, id: \.self) { object in
            self.content(object)
            /*NavigationLink(destination: DetailSeriesView(series: serie)) {
                HStack {
                    EmojiRatingView(rating: serie.rating)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(serie.title ?? "Unknown Title")
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(serie.producent ?? "Unknown Producent")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(self.howMuchTime(serie: serie))h")
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }*/

        }

        .onDelete(perform: deleteSeries) //Is there another way to use .onDelete? Maybe somewhere not in Generic file?
    }
}



func deleteSeries(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    for offset in offsets {

        let object = objects[offset]

        if object.isCustomImage == true {
            ImageToDirectory().deleteItemInDirectory(imageName: object.id.uuidString) //THERE IS A PROBLEM
        }

        moc.delete(object)
    }
    try? moc.save()
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A method like `deinit` is called when an object is removed from memory and that is not necessarily the same as deleting it from the persistent store so I don't think that is a way forward.

Instead I think you should look into overriding [didSave()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506585-didsave) from NSManagedObject which gets called when an object is saved or deleted and remove any images from there. You can override the method in an extension but since you are confused about your core data classes I suggest you read about [generating code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data/generating_code) for Core Data entities.